# How to kill rectangle but like ordinary kill in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, kill, rectangles

I don't know how to express it. Please see the example below.

Input:

```
a
bc
deffffffff
gh
i
```

I set mark before **"c"** and current cursor after **"h"**. And hit `C-x r k` that is `M-x kill-rectangle`. I assume there is no whitespace in the input, output and kill ring buffer.

Output:

```
a
b
dffffffff
g
i
```

Kill ring:

```
c
e
h
```

But what I want to get is following output and kill ring.

Desired output:

```
a
b
d
g
i
```

Desired kill ring:

```
c
effffffff
h
```

Is there any way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Just add a bunch of spaces after `h`, then `C-x r k`. Region isn't visible but it will still work. Finally, `delete-trailing-whitespace`.

Comment: Yes that's what I've been doing. But I didn't notice `delete-trailing-whitespace` after yank. It's very useful. Thanks. And more smarter way  is welcome!

Answer (score 3):

`cua-mode`'s rectangle manipulation functions are pretty sophisticated. For your use case it allows you to mark rectangle with `cua-set-rectangle-mark` and then copy the rectangle with `cua-copy-rectangle`. Finally paste using `cua-paste`. Here is an example

1) First enable `cua-mode` by doing <kbd>M-x</kbd>`cua-mode`<kbd>RET</kbd>

2) Start marking rectangle with `cua-set-rectangle-mark` (bound to <kbd>C-RET</kbd>)

[image: rectangle selection with cua-mode]

3) Copy the rectangle selected with `cua-copy-rectangle` (bound to <kbd>M-w</kbd>) OR kill the rectangle with `cua-cut-rectangle` (bound to <kbd>C-w</kbd>)

4) Finally paste with `cua-paste` (bound to <kbd>C-y</kbd>)

**UPDATE**: In Emacs 24.4 (not released yet), you can use cua-rectangle without having to enable `cua-mode`, the relevant command is `cua-rectangle-mark-mode`.

Comment: In Emacs-24.4, you could just use `M-x cua-rectangle-mark-mode` without having to enable cua-mode.

Answer (score 1):

One way, but it messes with whitespace:

1. Enter Picture mode with `M-x picture-mode`.
2. Start the region at the same place, but then move the cursor to the whitespace under after the last `f`.
3. Kill: `C-x r k`.
4. Exit picture mode with `C-c C-c`. This has the secondary effect of deleting trailing whitespace. Also, the killed rectangle is padded with whitespace.